# how to get values from two tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables **A** and **B**  , table **A** contains some columns and table **B** have some columns , there is one column same in both tables.

> I have a value for table **B** and and based on that value i have to find another column' rows value , and based on those values(which got from table **B**) ,i have to find some columns rows from table **A**

Comment: What is your question exactly ? Give us some query ?

Comment: table A has column groupId and userId (there is no primary key in table A), table B has groupId(this is the primary key in table B) ,groupName , and i have only value of userId , so i want all group name from table B which does't belongs to that userId

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use the [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) statement  :

Example of tables :

Table A : `A.id, A.column1, A.column2`
Table B : `B.id, B.column1, B.column2, B.a_id`

**SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.id
```

**PHP**

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.id';
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
   var_dump($row);
}
```

Comment: accepted your answer but can you again read my question in comments below the question , i tried to explain more.

Answer (score 2):

A simple join query:

```
SELECT a.*,b.*
FROM B
INNER JOIN A
 ON(A.<Same_Col> = B.<Same_Col>)
```

Switch `a.*,b.*` to the columns you want to select.

[You can read about joins syntax here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)